# Remove 'pid="%" dateline="%"' string from a quote tag using SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm converting my MyBB board to phpBB. The ONLY issue I'm having is that MyBB has quote tags like this:

```
[quote="Username" pid="4993" dateline="1703638754"]
```

But phpBB3 uses this:

```
[quote="Username"]
```

All I'd like to do is find any posts that contain the first format and change it into the second format within the database, then run the conversion again, which will fix the issue.

I tried this, but it only works if the post itself opens with a quote. Also if there are successive quote tags it doesn't work on them

```
UPDATE mybb_posts
SET message = 
  CONCAT(
    '%[quote="',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, 'quote="', -1), '"', 1),
    '"]%',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, '"]', -1)
  ) WHERE `message` LIKE '%[quote=\"%\" pid=\"%\" dateline=\"%\"]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regexp_replace` like:

```
UPDATE  mybb_posts
SET     message = REGEXP_REPLACE(message, 
            '" pid="[^"]*" dateline="[^"]*"]', 
            '"]')
```

The `[^"]*` snippet means any character other than `"` occuring zero or more times.

[Example at DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ku-byApm)

Comment: That's done it!!! Thank you so much! Happy new year.

Answer (score -2):

This query will be helpful for you.

```php
UPDATE mybb_posts
SET message = 
  CONCAT(
    '%[quote="',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, 'quote="', -1), '"', 1),
    '"]%',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, '"', -1)
  )
WHERE message LIKE '%[quote="%" pid="%" dateline="%"]%'
```

And an alternative could be:

```
UPDATE mybb_posts
SET message = 
  CONCAT(
    '%[quote="',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, 'quote="', -1), '"', 1),
    '"]%',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, '"]', -1)
  ) 
WHERE `message` LIKE '%[quote="%" pid="%" dateline="%"]%'
   OR `message` LIKE '%[quote="%" dateline="%"]%'
   OR `message` LIKE '%[quote="%" pid="%"]%';
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. All of the posts now look like this - in their entirety. All content has gone

```%[quote="Username"]% />```

Comment: not helpful, because no explanation is available, and results (first query) seems not OK. see: https://dbfiddle.uk/oBUG85oO